# flask isnt reading or interpreting css file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm basically trying to follow this tutorial ( http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/an-introduction-to-pythons-flask-framework/)

Now when the css part comes in, and i copy the code it simply wont come out styled even afterr main.css is added it still shows up unstyled like if it wasn't importing the css file here's the HTML code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask</title>    
    <strong><link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"></strong>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Flask App</h1>
      </div>
     </header>

    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

layout.html ^
Home.html   v

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="jumbo">
    <h2>Welcome to the Flask app<h2>
    <h3>This is the home page for the Flask app<h3>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

routes.py   v

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)      

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Most of the time this comes about because you do not have your CSS inside of the `static` folder (e. g. `project-name/static/css/main.css`, where `routes.py` is at `project-name/routes.py`.

Comment: the folder is set up ( flaskapp/static/css/main.css) and the (routes.py) is in flaskapp folder, which im pretty sure is how you are telling me to set up as, but still wont work-_-

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the directory structure of your app. By default, flask looks for the static directory in the same level as the file that the app object is created in. This is the example structure for a small application from the flask docs.

```
/yourapplication
    /yourapplication.py
    /static
       /style.css
    /templates
        layout.html
        index.html
        login.html
```

You can also change the location of the static files by setting the "static_folder" attribute on the app object. [Check the docs here for setting the static_folder](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/)

Comment: Right now i have it set up ( flaskapp/static/css/main.css) and then (routes.py) is in flaskapp folder (flaskapp/routes.py)... should i re arrange it like you are saying (flaskapp/static/main.css) nd leave routes.py in flaskapp foldr?

Comment: Just tryed to rearrange or basically delete the css folder and just have files in static folder still didn't really make a difference-_-

Comment: where are you templates stored ? are they like flaskapp/templates/layout.html etc ?

Comment: yeah, routes.py, or wherever you create the app should be at the same level as the static folder.

Comment: yes ( flaskapp/templates/layout.html) and routes.py is at same level as static folder checking out the inspect element and its reading the css file as text/html and before it uploads it reads 404 error(main.css
/css
GET
404
NOT FOUND
text/html
localhost/:5
Parser
379 B
0 B)

Comment: I added type="text/css" still didnt make a diff...                                                    Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Figured it out, I changed layout.html to index.html and took off the <strong> that where around the <link> nd fixed the problem.. Many thanks to all the help given:D  !

Comment: Right on, have fun with Flask